# HandlebarsJS + BackboneJS Loop through array of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I want to display a list of musical artists sorted by the beginning letter.

so I have this Backbone View:

```
function (App, Backbone, utils) {

    // Create a new module.
    var AllArtists = App.module();

    // Create view
    AllArtists.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: 'allArtistsList',
        initialize: function() {
            //this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this);
        },
        afterRender: function(){
            var col1 = new Backbone.Collection();
            col1.url = App.APIO + '/i/search/artist?name=a';
            col1.fetch({success: function(){
                console.log(col1);
            }});
            this.insertView('.artistsA', new AllArtists.View({collection: col1}));

            var col2 = new Backbone.Collection();
            col2.url = App.APIO + '/i/search/artist?name=b';
            col2.fetch({success: function(){
                console.log(col2);
            }});
            this.insertView('.artistsB', new AllArtists.View({collection: col2}));          
        }
    });

    return AllArtists;
}
```

Then I have my Handlebars HTML:

```
<div class="artistsA">
    {{#each this}}
        <a href="{{name}}">{{name}}</a>
    {{/each}}   
</div>
```

So far, my JSON looks like this (in this case letter a):

```
data: [ 
        {
           artist_id:78, 
           name:A Band Of Boys
         },
          {
           artist_id:79, 
           name:a Beautiful Friend
         },
         {
           artist_id:80, 
           name:A Camp
        } 
        etc. etc...
```

I can see that my console.log returns the data but I get a blank page so it indicates that there is something wrong with my Handlebars?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Basically fetch() is asynchronous, it will internally call Ajax request which is asynchronous.
You have to call `insertView()` once your fetch call is success i.e on success callback. 
You are observing blank page because you are trying to call insertView() before you got data.

If you want to make it synchronous request, you can use the property `{async:false}`

```
col1.fetch({async:false});
```

Comment: hmm okay, but when I add `insertView()` into success fallback I get `undefined is not a function` - referring to `this.insertView()` ??

Comment: You should use global context instead of success callback context, I mean 'this' is different outside success callback and within callback.. Solution: Make a copy of global context and use that...  Ex : var self = this;  col2.fetch({success: function(){
                self.insertView(...);
            }});

Comment: ok thanks, that cleared that error :-) Even though, still blank page/empty html even if the console.log tells me that data is available... :-/